# Update "mysql_fetch_array" to "$wpdb->get_results" in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins

I'm updating some old wordpress plugin files and understand I need to update "mysql_fetch_array" to "$wpdb->get_results" to get the plugin to talk with the database.

Here is the code where "mysql_fetch_array" is used:

```
//select ads id's  stored into db table
$sql  = "SELECT id FROM $table_name_ad_google";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
```

How do I rewrite this to use $wpdb->get_results?

Comment: $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql); this returns an object. Not enough?

Comment: Since you're only interested in one field you can also use [$wpdb->get_col](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Column): `$ids = $wpdb->get_col('SELECT id FROM '.$table_name_ad_google);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_employee WHERE 1=1";
$query = $wpdb->get_results($sql,ARRAY_A);
foreach($query as $row){
/*$row["your column name"];*/
}
```